# How can I implement a copy constructor to this program?

Tags: c++, oop, initialization, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point{
private: 
  int x, y;
public:
  Point(int x, int y) { this->x = x; this->y = y } 
  Point(const Point &p) { x = p.x; y = p.y; }

  int getX(void) { return x; }
  int getY(void) { return y; }
};

int main(){
    Point myPt(1,2);
    Point myPt2 = myPt;

    cout << myPt.getX() << " " << myPt.getY() << endl;
    cout << myPt2.getX() << " " << myPt2.getY() << endl;
    
  return 0;
}
```

I want to set myPt2 to a different value while keeping myPt values the same, even after setting myPt2 equal to myPt (redefinition error when I do this). For example, Point myPt(1,2); Point myPt2 = myPt; ....print output, then set myPt2(5, 5) and print statements again: I want the output 1   2 \n5   5.

Comment: You _have_ implemented a copy constructor.  The "redefinition error" you mention is likely because you're trying to define an identifier with the same name.  You should have shown this code, then we could have a real discussion.  But because you didn't, I assume you wrote `Point myPt2(5, 5);` which is a redefinition, whereas you wanted `myPt2 = Point(5,5);`

Comment: The vast majority of the time you don't need a copy constructor when all of the resources owned by the class are self-managing. In this case the class's only resources are `x` and `y`, and `int`s look after their own copying. See the [Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for details.

Comment: Only mistake I see in the above code is a missing semicolon: `Point(int x, int y) { this->x = x; this->y = y*>>>;<<< }`

Comment: Side note: Read up on the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). It's not that important here, `Point(int x, int y) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }` becomes `Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {  }`, but it will save you a lot of trouble later.

Comment: `int getX(void) { return x; }` should be `int getX() const { return x; }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are looking for a way to make below code work:

```cpp
int main(){
    Point myPt(1,2);
    Point myPt2 = myPt;
    myPt2(5, 5);

    cout << myPt.getX() << " " << myPt.getY() << endl;    // prints "1 2"
    cout << myPt2.getX() << " " << myPt2.getY() << endl;  // prints "5 5"
}
```

To allow the syntax`myPt2(5, 5)`, you must overload the call operator, `operator()`, to accept 2 integers:

```cpp
class Point {
  ⋮
public:
  void operator()(int x, int y)
  {
      this->x = x; this->y = y;
  }
  ⋮
};
```

---

---

However, I strongly suggest to not go this approach. Instead, when you want to reassign values to `myPt2`, you really should be calling the copy assignment operator using the following syntax:

```cpp
myPt2 = Point(5, 5);
```

To write your own copy assignment operator, it would be something like:

```cpp
class Point {
  ⋮
public:
  Point& operator=(const Point &p)
  {
      x = p.x;
      y = p.y;
      return *this;
  }
  ⋮
};
```

---

In fact, based on what your class do, you really don't need to write either copy constructor or the copy assignment operator. This is all you need:

```cpp
class Point{
private: 
  int x, y;
public:
  Point(int x, int y) { this->x = x; this->y = y; } 

  int getX(void) { return x; }
  int getY(void) { return y; }
};
```

Any kind of copy construction will be done automatically. You really only need to define your own copy constructors if you either have non-copyable members, or if you are looking for some custom copy behavior, such as doing deep copying a pointer.

Comment: Okay thanks. So if you wrote a copy constructor for this program how would you do it? Also I'm seeing in my Gaddis book where you have to dynamically allocate memory and use a pointer variable. Can you explain this to me in plain english please. I've done my research and I'm just not understanding a definitive way to use a copy constructor all the ones on youtube and books look different. What is a way to code this up that works every time? I'm a university student, still learning. Hope that question is worth your time. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Descode `Point(const Point &p) = default;` Your copy constructor is correct, but not necessary. The compiler will generate it for you if you leave it out or explicitly `default` it.

Comment: I've noticed that...which confuses me even more...I've been studying this for a week now and I just dont understand it which is insane because this isnt the most complicated concept I've learned in college thus far..

Comment: The operator overload is a horrendous anti-pattern.  I don't support that advice.

Comment: Yes, a deep copy is what I'm trying to accomplish here. I just dont understand this from my professors slide. Can someone please explain whats going on here...is the pointer being dereferenced when assigned to v also?                   class CpClass {
   private:
    int *p;
   public:
    CpClass(int v=0)
      { p = new int; *p = v;}
    ~CpClass(){delete p;}
  };

Comment: When a class contains simple members or complex members that manage their own copying (have a correct copy constructor and assignment operator), you need do nothing. The example with the pointer, the object pointed at needs special handing. The default behaviour for copying a pointer is you wind up with two pointers containing the same address, both point to the same object. If instance reaches its destructor and `delete p;`, `p` is deleted for both instances, leaving the still-surviving instance as a timebomb that will blow up in the near future.

Comment: This one needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator that allocate a new `int` that is a copy of the `int` pointed at by the source instance: `CpClass(const CpClass& src): p(new int(*src.p) ) {}`

Comment: @Descode No, you are not deep copying any members here, or at least not the deep copy I was trying to say. Unless you have any owning pointer, which can be spotted with the usage of `new` or `unique_ptr`, then you likely don't need to deal with any deep copy.

Comment: A note about `unique_ptr`: It is a smart class that knows how to manage its resources correctly. When it goes out of scope, it cleans up the mess for you. But because it is intended to be unique, it cannot be copied. Only moved. No deep copy here. If you want two objects both pointing at the same object and guarantees that the object will not be deleted until all of the sharers are gone, use `shared_ptr` Also not a deep copy. To get a deep copy, you write it yourself or use a container which handles deep copies.

Comment: @paddy operator overload is not an anti-pattern here, while not needed, creating custom copy assignment operator is operator overload. However, I agree overloading call operator is anti-pattern here, and I regret giving that out as the answer first.

Comment: I'm with paddy, mostly. The way you used the call operator in the original example rather than an assignment operator was misleading. I just figured you'd misread the question and would be back shortly with a better answer.

Comment: My point was that defining a function-like operator overload to modify the value is an abuse of operator semantics.  It's leaning on syntactic sugar to provide some familiarity with the constructor, instead of a well-specified call (for example: `Set(int, int)`) that is self-documenting.  Just because you _can_ do it doesn't mean you _should_.  And when you opened your answer with "here's how to do it" followed by one of the worst possible solutions, it prompted my reaction and comment.  It _is_ an anti-pattern to use an obscure overload instead of a descriptive function.

Comment: @paddy I agree with you, I just don't want to shoot OP down the idea of operator overload in general when you really mean the call operator is inappropriate at this circumstance.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep That's what I meant, but at about the same time I wrote my comment, you also updated the answer to add extra stuff.  I edited my comment somewhat in response to that, but perhaps the intent was diluted.  I was explicitly talking about your first solution, not operator overloading in general. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your program already has a copy contructor -- `Point(const Point &p)` -- which is used to construct a new Point object from another Point object.

To change an existing Point object, you want a copy assignment operator.  You can define that in your Point class as:

```
Point &operator=(const Point &p) { x = p.x; y = p.y; return *this; }
```

or even just

```
Point &operator=(const Point &) = default;
```